# How can i identify which type of encryption am i using?

Tags: encryption

my friend created his platform using laravel, and he encrypted the users password using laravel Hash. I never worked with laravel. I'm building a simple Android application to list all the users from his website, using PHP and Java, and i would like to decrypt the passwords for the login.

I usually use md5:

```
$password = md5($_GET['password']);
```

But he used a different hash. My password appears encrypted like this:

```
Q5joXS5QBA0xdV2Ed2c80e12ac10766d48ef5d8a916e445064091725156d7776958a3937b5cbe79
```

Thanks.

Comment: md5 is *not encryption* (its hashing) and it is not reversible

Comment: If your friend is hashing the password then it can't be decrypted: hashes are one-way functions.

Comment: *"I usually use md5"* You shouldn't! Use at least SHA-256 with a salt and many iterations: PBKDF2 or even scrypt

Answer (score 2):

Some small research seems to show that they are hashed using Bcrypt. This is different to encrypting because it is one way. So to check if the two passwords match, you will need to encrypt the user input with Bcrypt and then check if the two match.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security - Info on BCrypt.

You could use this to check if your passwords match up.

http://www.bcrypt-generator.com/

EDIT: I would advise against using md5 encryption as it is not very secure and it can "decrypted" by brute force.

Example: http://www.hashkiller.co.uk/md5-decrypter.aspx